# Minecraft /score board

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a new server and as I was creating some shops I realized that they could go into the negatives. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me the command to ether make it so the player gets banned for 5 minutes when they go into the negatives **OR** If someone could tell me a command to make it so they can not go into the negatives. For Java

Comment: Please read [What to do before asking a Minecraft command question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent scoreboard score from dropping below zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319463/prevent-scoreboard-score-from-dropping-below-zero)

Comment: For your health

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: What doesn't work? The solution isn't what you want or are you having trouble making it work?

Comment: don't need it I figured something out