# Minecraft combining /testfor names and enchants in one command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

so I made this command to test for if a player has a $50 dollar check on my minecraft server so i can then link that up to a command that will clear the check and pay them. My issue is I can't seem to figure out how to add an enchant to the command. The checks are all enchanted with Unbreaking 10 but I can't seem to figure out how to add that constraint in the command. The command (so far) is:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"$50 Check"}}}]}
```

If anyone would be willing to help me add an enchant constrain so players can't just use anvils to forge checks that would be awesome. (It is a 1.12.2 server btw)

**EDIT** This question has changed to combining my command

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"$50 Check"}}}]}
```

and the enchantment constraint, `[{id:34s,lvl:10s}`. If someone could help me I've searched to try to find how to do this but I really can't find a way that works.

Comment: If your question isn't a duplicate, show us **why** it's not a duplicate.  That means editing the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enchantment section goes inside the tag section after display.

Here is the setup minus the information and spaced out:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{ id:"...", tag:{  display:{...}, ench:[...]  }}]}
```

Here is the final command:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"$50 Check"},ench:[{id:34s,lvl:10s}]}}]}
```

**A warning**, duplication glitches are discovered often, when using an item based currency form like this, the items can be easily duplicated which then ruins the economy.  I strongly recommend using a scoreboard based currency instead.  [Here is a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255371/186522) which, the question itself, provides a lot of good information on scoreboard shop.

Comment: Hey, no problems, glad you got a working solution.  One thing, in the help center on the page [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) they ask not to use comments for thank you only comments.